# Converting a pandas dataframe to nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas with 39 variables. I need to convert this into JSON format in such a way that it has 3 keys. For e.g.

```
{"Key1":"Var1","Key2":{"Var2":"25","Var3":"10","Var4":"5","Var5":"2"},"Key3":{"Var6":"1","Var7":"0","Var8":"10"}}
```

also need the values associated with variables as string

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to use the [.to_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_json) method of your dataframe object?

Comment: What does your pandas data frame look like? It is difficult to see how the columns and rows map to that JSON. At the very least, it would be helpful to show what the pandas data frame version of that JSON is.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, how big your data frame is, but you could iterate over it, process every row and save it to JSON file. Let me show you on the following example.

First, I will import packages and make example data set:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {'Var1': 23, 'Var2': 25, 'Var3': 10, 'Var4': 5, 'Var5': 2, 'Var6': 1, 'Var7': 0, 'Var8': 10},
        {'Var1': 24, 'Var2': 26, 'Var3': 11, 'Var4': 6, 'Var5': 3, 'Var6': 2, 'Var7': 1, 'Var8': 11},
        {'Var1': 25, 'Var2': 27, 'Var3': 12, 'Var4': 7, 'Var5': 4, 'Var6': 3, 'Var7': 2, 'Var8': 12},
        {'Var1': 26, 'Var2': 28, 'Var3': 13, 'Var4': 8, 'Var5': 5, 'Var6': 4, 'Var7': 3, 'Var8': 13},
    ]
)

print(df)
```

The code produces this output:

```
   Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4  Var5  Var6  Var7  Var8
0    23    25    10     5     2     1     0    10
1    24    26    11     6     3     2     1    11
2    25    27    12     7     4     3     2    12
3    26    28    13     8     5     4     3    13
```

Now, I will show you the main part of the code:

```
with open('test_json_file.json', 'w') as file:
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        json_to_save = {
            "Key1": str(row.Var1),
            "Key2": {
                "Var2": str(row.Var2),
                "Var3": str(row.Var3),
                "Var4": str(row.Var4),
                "Var5": str(row.Var5)
            },
            "Key3": {
                "Var6": str(row.Var6),
                "Var7": str(row.Var7),
                "Var8": str(row.Var8)
            }
        }
        file.write(json.dumps(json_to_save) + '\n')
```

The code creates `test_json_file.json` file and saves `json_to_save` json defined in for loop on new row in the file, e. g. on the first line of the file, you will find this json: `{"Key1": "23", "Key2": {"Var2": "25", "Var3": "10", "Var4": "5", "Var5": "2"}, "Key3": {"Var6": "1", "Var7": "0", "Var8": "10"}}`.

I hope it will help.

Comment: This is amazing @Jaroslav! It solved my purpose. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @ManojSharma, I am glad the answer solved your problem. In that case, please, do not forget to [accept and upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.